# AWS MySQL to GCP BigQuery data migration

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, aws-data-pipeline

I'm planning a Data Migration from AWS MySQL instances to GCP BigQuery. I don't want to migrate every MySQL Database because finally I want to create a Data Warehouse using BigQuery.

Would exporting AWS MySQL DB to S3 buckets as csv/json/avro, then transfer to GCP buckets be a good option? What would be the best practices for this Data pipeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this was a MySQL to MySQL migration; there were other possible options. But in this case the option you mentioned is perfect.. Also, remember that your MySQL database will keep getting updated.. So, your destination DB might have some records missed out.. because it is not real-time DB transfer.

Comment: Hi Deepak, thank you for the reply the plan is to migrate archived data at the initial phase, by the time of this migration completion expecting the system too would be migrated to GCP. Even after the migration to GCP I will have to deal with MySQL data bases hence I'll keep in my mind your point for the real time Data transfer, thank you again..

Answer (score 0):

Your proposal of exporting to S3 files should work OK, and to export the files you can take advantage of the [AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.S3.html)

With that service you can do either a once-off export to S3, or an incremental export with Change Data Capture. Unfortunately, since BigQuery is not really designed for working with changes on its tables, implementing CDC can be a bit cumbersome (although totally doable). You need to take into account the cost of transferring data across providers.

Another option, which would be much easier for you, is to use the same AWS Database Migration service to [move data directly to Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.Redshift.html).

In this case, you would get change data capture automatically, so you don't need to worry about anything. And RedShift is an excellent tool to build your data warehouse.

If you don't want to use RedShift for any reason, and you prefer a fully serverless solution, then you can easily use [AWS Glue Catalog to read](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/glue-athena.html) from your databases and export to AWS Athena.

The cool thing about the AWS based solutions is everything is tightly integrated, you can use the same account/users for billing, IAM, monitoring... and since you are moving data within a single provider, there is no extra charge for networking, no latency, and potentially fewer security issues.

Comment: Hi Javier, thank you for the comment, ultimately I need to migrate all my archived data from AWS to GCP, but your feedback is highly appreciated! :)

Comment: Just remember to compress your export before moving to gcp, so you can save on network egress